# Word Wrapping -- Possible to highlight just one horizontal line of many?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I like automatically highlighting the line of code that I'm working on, but the current setting highlights the entire wrapped line -- sometimes extending several horizontal lines on the page.

```
// If enabled, will highlight any line with a caret
"highlight_line": true,
```

Is there any way to just highlight one horizontal line of text, even though the wrapped line might consist of several horizontal lines of code?

Comment: The plugin CursorRuler gives a vertical line, which is a workaround.  In such a case, the horizontal line highlight can be disabled so as to avoid distraction caused by multiple wrapped lines being highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Sublime Text 2.  The nightly build of Emacs / Aquamacs, however, does offer this feature.